# Why can't uniformCount equal to GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS

Tags: opengl-es

According to the documention for [`glGetActiveUniformsiv`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glGetActiveUniformsiv.xhtml), `GL_INVALID_VALUE` is generated when

> uniformCount is greater than or equal to the value of GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS for program.

Why can't uniformCount equal to `GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS`?

Comment: What API call are you asking about? It looks like you're quoting documentation from a specific call, but you're not specifying which one it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a mistake in the man page. Unfortunately, the man pages are not always a reliable source of information. The final word is always the spec. I haven't been able to find this error in the ES 3.0 spec. The only related error I could find is:

> For GetActiveUniformsiv, uniformIndices speciﬁes an array of uniformCount indices in this list. If index or any value in uniformIndices is greater than or equal to the value of ACTIVE_UNIFORMS, the error INVALID_VALUE is generated.

There is no limit on the `uniformCount`, as far as I can tell.

In the OpenGL 4.5 spec, `glGetActiveUniformsiv()` is described as equivalent to a loop where `glGetProgramResourceiv()` is called `uniformCount` times. `glGetPogramResourceiv()` documents a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error for invalid indices. But there is nothing about a limitation for `uniformCount`.

Comment: Hmm. But when I call glGetActiveUniformsiv with uniformCount=0 when GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORMS == 0, GL_INVALID_VALUE error is generated.

Comment: The way I read it, that should not be the case if all other arguments are valid. Could be a bug in the driver if that's happening.

Comment: Could be. I'm getting different result when running in CodeXL vs running directly.